# Can't enable wireless on Lenovo Thinkpad Edge 520

Tags: wireless, thinkpad, lenovo

I've tried several things like mentioned in the forums, but I'm at a loss.  Everything works fine except wireless Internet.  I see using Terminal that it detects the drive but it is disabled.  I go to enable it, and it quickly puts the check mark on, then checkmark comes off.  No error messages.
I tried checking for updates, installing a Windows based wireless driver and happend on Ubuntu version 10, 11.04 and 11.10 now.  Same issue.  I really want to switch over to using Ubuntu, but if I can't get a basic thing like wireless Internet, I can't begin to try various programs, etc.
My laptop is only a few months old and came with Windows 7 if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heh, you should disable acer_vmi module, it's quite common,
this thread should fix this:

[Wireless doesn't work on a  Lenovo V570](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77719/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-lenovo-v570)

in short, add the following line in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

```
blacklist acer-wmi
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  This worked like a charm.  You're a rock star!  Now I can use wireless when I'm not at work and really start learning more about Ubuntu.